# can't put a framelayout inside a relativelayout?

Tags: android, xml

So it works fine unless I try to make it fit in the center, then it makes my app crash whenever I run it. I tried changing the framelayout to a linearlayout but it still crashes. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/current"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/current"
    android:background="@drawable/wood_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recent_notes_list">

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gen_note"
    android:id="@+id/current"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
    android:alpha=".75"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="35sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/previous_txt"
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:alpha=".5" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="35sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/next_button"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/current"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="33sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:background="@drawable/parchment_back"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you attach the crash log?

Comment: Also there are 2 linear layouts so we cannot figure which linear layout is the one you changed.

Comment: The one that's not in a scrollview, the second one. I get a message in the emulator saying "this program has stopped" and in the adb logs: DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '2860': closed DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '28909': closed

Comment: And the logcat. I had to abbreviate that alphebet part. 05-23 14:12:28.616 665-694/android.process.acore D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 208K, 2% free 16802K/17064K, paused 188ms, total 190ms 05-23 14:12:53.700 665-696/android.process.acore I/ContactLocale﹕ AddressBook Labels [en_US]: [, A, B, C, D, E,.....] 05-23 14:18:22.273 665-686/android.process.acore D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 362K, 3% free 16952K/17368K, paused 60ms, total 68ms 05-23 14:21:02.945 665-665/android.process.acore D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 208K, 4% free 16813K/17368K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 89ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, never mind. I guess for some reason android doesn't like my parchment texture. I kind of don't need it anyways so I just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Clean

Sometimes it helps

Answer (score 0):

Weird.. I guess it's only crashing if I assign a background image... The funny thing is, this is sorta why I'm using a frame layout anyways (to layer things).. That SORTA fixes my problem I guess.